# Remove everything except words and spaces between word

Tags: javascript

The element contains the following content, where the desired solution is to clean "everything" except the words and space between

```js
var textContent = " +(269) Yukon Makukon"
var cleanContent = textContent.replace(/[^A-Za-z]/g, ``)

document.write(cleanContent);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add space character in your regex and then just `.trim()` it to format it nicely.

```js
var textContent = " +(269) Yukon Makukon"
var cleanContent = textContent.replace(/[^A-Za-z ]/g, ``).trim();

document.write(cleanContent);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let textContent = " +(269) Yukon Makukon";
let result = textContent.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/g, "").trim();
console.log(result); // => Yukon Makukon
```

This will remove all special characters along with any extra white space.

Comment: No worries, Adeel. All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Or, you may use an arrow function and return empty string or just `.replace(/[^A-Za-z ]/g, '')` will be fine if you just want to ignore them:

```js
var textContent = " +(269) Yukon Makukon"
// this way, you can replace them with any character if you wish.
// you were ignoring space ---------------------V
var cleanContent = textContent.replace(/[^A-Za-z ]/g, u=>'');

document.write(cleanContent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var cleanContent = textContent.replace(/[^a-zA-Z]/g, '').trim();
```